# javascript regular expression to replace string

Tags: regex, replace

I have unspecified number of html inputs:

```
<input id="ageInput" />
<input id="nameInput" />
```

...

and having the following string which is built based on inputs:

```
s = "{ 'age': '{ageInput}', 'name': '{nameInput}'}"
```

how could I use regular expression to replace the above string to reflect the current inputs values like this:

```
s = "{ 'age': " + $('#ageInput').val() + ", 'name': " + $('#nameInput').val() + " }"
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. How do you exactly want to deal with quotes?

Comment: Neither of those strings are syntactically valid.

Comment: assume you have to make a key-value pair request to transfer some data from specific html inputs, I would like to substitute html input value instead of {inputname}.
vittore has the perfect answer. See it below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your original question, use `replace` method of string , which accepts function as parameter:

```
s  = s.replace(/\{([^{}]+)\}/g, function (match, g1) { 
   return $("#" + g1).val()
})
```

But I would rather use `JSON.stringify`:

```
var s =  "{ 'age': '{ageInput}', 'name': '{nameInput}'}"
  , controlMap = JSON.parse(s)
  , data = {}

for(var i in controlMap) {
    data[i] = $(controlMap[i]).val()
}

var str = JSON.stringify(data)
```

Comment: What does the `g1` parameter represent?  I can't find it documented: http://goo.gl/wd8fYH

Comment: @Jack7890 it is first group. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter referenced as p1...pN in the table